# ASP.NET proxy script?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, proxy

Is there a good example somewhere of an ASP script which accepts a GET request for a URL, and returns the contents of that URL, passing along any headers sent in the request?

I'm working on a Silverlight app and am trying to work around some cross-domain web service issues, so I'd like to just proxy the requests through my own domain. Searching for "asp proxy" gets me lots of irrelevant results.

Comment: when searching for ASP.NET info, be sure to specify `ASP.NET` and not just `ASP`.  They are two different things :)

Answer (score 1):

The code in this Reverse Proxy on CodeProject should do the trick: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/HTTPReverseProxy.aspx.

Comment: I found that one, but I'm wondering if a sample from 2004 is still relevant in 2012. I'll also need to put this on Azure, so I'm wondering if it'll work there. I guess it's worth a shot.

Comment: No dice. The Web.config schema has changed a lot in the intervening time, and even once I resolved those errors, requesting http://host/http://othersite.com/ just spewed more errors.

Comment: The web.config snippets are still valid.  Looking at the comments people have had it working quite recently.  You need to make requests in the format `http://revrseproxyurl/http//www.site.com/`.

Comment: My requests were in the write format -- the SO editor just mangled my paste. I haven't had any luck with that, so I'm trying http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite, which seems like a more official/supported/modern way to go anyway.